# My attempted posted answer says looks like spam and won't post

Tags: discussion

[image]I'm all about sharing research. My lengthy and detailed response to a question, including a working script will not post because "it looks like spam". Anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Hi, please know if it’s link only answer it may get flagged easilly. Please share a picture in worst case of what the answer look like.

Comment: Edited as requested.

Comment: I don't know about "spam" (only SE devs could answer that one), but as an answer, I can't imagine an on-topic question to which it would be appropriate.

Comment: It would help me answer if you would include a link to the question which you were attempting to answer. Maybe that sets a context which the anti-spam machinery considers. I'm sad that you are running into this obstacle. It looks like you have good information to share, and an amusing writing style.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid I can't tell you what "looks like spam", but I can tell you what I do in situations like this.

**1. Fewer domain names**, or text which looks like domain names. You mention `example.com` and related subdomains constantly. I can imagine an anti-spam filter being suspicious of too great a proportion of the text being URL text. Maybe you could work around this by saying "your domain name" instead of spelling out the example domain name. Similarly, say "the www subdomain" instead of spelling out the subdomain name.

**2. Mark domain names as code**, using backticks. It's conceivable that an anti-spam engine will be more lenient with URL text marked up as code, because URLs will be more common in code.

**3. Say less**. Look at what the question asks. What part of your draft addresses that?  What part goes beyond?  Cut the part that goes beyond.  But what I do with answers that swell into small dissertations is to make the blog posts. I don't have to answer to any anti-spam filters on my own blog, and the search engines can still find the content.

Comment: I would be surprised to learn that SE devs flag as spam a domain reserved by RFC for documentation.